# Java "int i = byte1 | 0x0200" vs "int i = byte1"?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

In the page [Wikipedia - Shifts in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_Java):

> In bit and shift operations, the type `byte` is implicitly converted to
>   `int`. **If the byte value is negative**, the highest bit is one, then ones
>   are used to fill up the extra bytes in the int. So
>
> ```
> byte b1=-5; int i = b1 | 0x0200;
> ```
>
> will give i == -5 as result.

I understand that `0x0200` is equal to `0b0000 0010 0000 0000`. But what is the significance of `0x0200` in the passage shown above?

I mean—`b1 | 0x0200` will always be equal to `i` (see "**My Test**" below), then in the passage above, why not simply write `byte b1=-5; int i = b1`?

**My Test**:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    final byte min_byte = Byte.MIN_VALUE; // -128
    final byte limit = 0; // according to the bolded words in the passage
    for (byte b = min_byte; b < limit; ++b) {
        final int i1 = b;
        final int i2 = b | 0x0200;
        if (i1 != i2) { // this never happens!
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, Sorry that was a typo, edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what is the significance of 0x0200 in the passage shown above?

This is done for illustration purposes only: the value `0x200` ORs in a one in a position that is equal to `1` already. The idea is to show that the result is not `0x000002FB`, but actually `-5`, i.e. `0xFFFFFFFB`.

Comment: So in other words, you are saying that 0x0100 and 0x0300 and 0x0400 (and anything that is of the form 0xAB00) to 0xFF00 would have been appropriate for the passage?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that 0x0200 is equal to 0b1111 1110 0000 0000

No, it isn't. The correct value is given by,

```
int i = 0x0200; // <-- decimal 512
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
```

Which outputs

```
1000000000
```

If we examine your second value,

```
byte b1 = -5;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b1));
```

We get

```
11111111111111111111111111111011
```

Lining up both numbers

```
11111111111111111111111111111011
00000000000000000000001000000000
```

It seems clear that the result will be the bit value of `-5` (since the only `0` in `-5` is also `0` in `0x0200`). To determine the significance we can examine

```
int i = 0x0200; // <-- Decimal 512
System.out.println("Dec: " + Integer.toBinaryString(i).length());
```

Output

```
Dec: 10
```

So, the given bitwise OR will force the tenth bit to be true. It was true in your input byte, but if you used - Decimal 1535 (`0b 101 1111 1111`) then you would get,

```
System.out.println(1535 | 0x0200);
```

Output is

```
2047
```

Because if you perform a bitwise-or on the two numbers

```
01000000000
10111111111
```

you get

```
11111111111
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis-I think your messing around with others answers without proper intuition is irritating! I think the OP has already got what he wanted! If you are feeling uneasy, you must better write an answer for it! I seriously recommend you writing an answer for this if you are extremely unsatisfied with other answers!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, that's much better.

Comment: @shekharsuman I appreciate constructive criticism. If my answer is unclear I'd prefer to improve it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch-No SIR, your answer is best among all of us. But, I am just dis-satisfied with Mr. Sotirios Delimanolis' approach of criticising other's answers without having a proper thought over it! I again appreciate your answer!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Thanks alot for your answer! And I'm really sorry for my `1111...` typo in the question, have edited it.